# How to copy a kd-tree from host to driver in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have a kd-tree data structure like this

```
class KDTree{
   KDNode *root;
}
class KDNode{
   std::vector<Triangle*> triangles;//if isLeaf then triangles.size()=0
   AABB aabb;
   KDNode *left,*right;
   bool isLeaf;
}
class Triangle{
   Point3D p1,p2,p3;
}
class AABB{
   Point3D mins,maxs;
}
```

I can use this data structure in CPU, now I want to copy this tree to GPU (have constructed the tree on CPU).

I'm not exactly sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. Since you (likely) allocate nodes individually and separately, you have a large number of discontinguous areas of memory which you need to copy - meaning a high number of CUDA API calls to make.
2. Even when you copy the different nodes - they point to nodes on the host, not to the copies - so you would have to alter the pointers everywhere. A lot of time and effort.

Possible solutions:

1. Alter your representation of the tree so that the nodes are all in one big array of nodes (which you grow as necessary); and instead of pointers, you use indices into this array. Now, you'll just need to copy some root data, and this one (large) array; and to update the array address in the device-side version.
2. Use CUDA's allocation facilities to allocate *managed* memory - accessible with the same address both from the CUDA device (GPU) and from the host. That way you don't have to explicitly copy anything, and can keep the pointers with the same value. This has a performance penalty of course.

Note: Tree-like structures are quite inefficient for use in CUDA: Typically, different threads diverge, and a lot of time is spent in "pointer chasing" - making one indirect access after another, and another and so on. So it's not clear you'll get a lot of benefit, if any, from using a GPU with this structure.